# Django Keyword Search Not Working

Tags: python, django

I bought this book and Im busy working through it. Now what I found is that someone has already come across this same problem and posted here on this URL:

["Practical django Projects, 2nd ed., source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502492/practical-django-projects-2nd-ed-source-code)

Im having the exact same problem as above except that while it shows on the backend when I perform a search for a page linked to a certain keyword I get 0 results all the time. Can someone please help me out with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have posted there this answer, I am reposting it here, maybe it will help you.

Do you have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

in your `urls.py`? And also something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And also have you turned on admin app in settings?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

Comment: I think these configs are already there as admin site seems to be accessible.